Generic TypeScript for managing Supabase data
I have this "types.ts" that i use for using the types generated with Supabase CLI more efficently
import { Database } from './database.types';

export type Tables<T extends keyof Database['public']['Tables']> =
  Database['public']['Tables'][T]['Row'];

export type Enums<T extends keyof Database['public']['Enums']> =
  Database['public']['Enums'][T];

The problem is that i can't manage to make this work with a query that needs to have a join...
The code would still work fine, so for example
type EventListItemProps = {
  event: Tables\<"events"\>
}

will let me access event.name and also event.table1.name, but the IDE tells me (obviously) that "Property 'table1' does not exist on type"
i was thinking that maybe something like
type EventListItemProps = {
  event: Tables\<"events"\> & {
    table1: Tables\<"table1"\>;
  };
}

would work, but i should do it for every case of SELECT with a join and that would be awful...If is possible i would like to have something more generic, that can adapt to most of the cases.
Thanks for any help, and forgive me for my english!

Supabase has a tool that generates types for you based on your schema https://supabase.com/docs/guides/api/rest/generating-types. Inside this tool is a way to get the exact type for any join from the supabase request itself https://supabase.com/docs/guides/api/rest/generating-types#response-types-for-complex-queries

Supabase has a tool to generate the types for you (supabase-type-generator)
First generate the types
npx supabase gen types typescript --project-id "$PROJECT_REF" --schema public > types/supabase.ts
// or for local
npx supabase gen types typescript --local > types/supabase.ts


And then supabase can provide the type of any query like this:
const queryResult = supabase.from('events').select(`
  event_id,
  table1 (
    field1
  )
`)

type EventListItemProps = QueryData<typeof queryResult>

const { data, error } = await queryResult
if (error) throw error

const eventListItem: EventListItemProps = data


Thanks @EmandM, i added more info about my problem... I don't know if i'm doing things correctly i'm new on StackOverflow...

Thanks for your help, I would like to ask you one more thing to be able to configure my specific case correctly:
I currently have split the code into three files:
(The table "events" is actually called "eventi" and "table1" is "locali")
-api/events/index.ts
import { supabase } from '@/lib/supabase';
import { useQuery } from '@tanstack/react-query';

export const useEventList = () => {
    return useQuery({
        queryKey: ["eventi"],
        queryFn : async()=>{

          const {data, error} = await supabase
            .from("eventi")
            .select(`*, locale:locali(*)`);

          if(error)
            throw new Error(error.message);
          return data;
        }
      });
}

-My Home page (app/events/index.tsx)
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, FlatList, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import EventListItem from "@/components/eventi/EventListItem";
import { useEventList } from '@/api/events';



export default function Home() {
  
  const{data: eventi, error, isLoading} = useEventList();
  
  if(isLoading){
    return <ActivityIndicator />
  }
  
  if(error){
    return <Text>Ops, qualcosa è andato storto!</Text>
  }
  
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <FlatList
    style={{flex:1}}
    data = {eventi}
    renderItem={({item}) => <EventListItem evento={item}/>}
    numColumns={1}
    contentContainerStyle={{gap:10, padding:10}}
    // columnWrapperStyle={{gap:10}}
    />
    </View>
  );
}

-EventListItem component
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, Pressable, Image, } from 'react-native';
import {Tables} from "@/types";
import { Link } from 'expo-router';
import { Colors } from '@/constants/Colors';

type EventListItemProps = {
    evento: Tables<"eventi"> & {
        locale: Tables<"locali">;
      };
}

const EventListItem = ({evento}: EventListItemProps) => {
    const dayjs = require('dayjs');
    const eventDate = dayjs(evento.dt_inizio).format("DD/MM");
    return(
        <Link href={`/eventi/${evento.id}`} asChild>
            <Pressable style={styles.card}>
                {/* <Image
                    source = {{uri: evento.img || "" }}
                /> */}
                <Text>{evento.nome}</Text>
                <Text>{evento.locale.nome}</Text>
                <Text>{eventDate}</Text>
            </Pressable>
        </Link>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    card: {
        flex: 1,
        borderRadius: 7,
        paddingVertical: 5,
        paddingHorizontal: 8,
        backgroundColor: Colors.light.tabIconSelected,
    }
})

export default EventListItem;

Any advice is welcome, being at the beginning of my project I may as well change the structure and logic, for now I chose this one because by hanging around various tutorials I had found this one and it seemed neat
